# How to change default value of taxonomy term in View exposed filter drupal 7?

Tags: views

I have created view page to find events from Start date - End date and category(taxonomy terms). I have enabled expose filter on fields. How do I show '-select-' instead of '-any-'

or else is there any other method to show no result until user does not add filter value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To display Results Only when Criteria is selected :**

- In your view, change `Advanced Settings -> Exposed form style` **to** `Input required`

[image]

- In **Exposed Form style settings** you could define the text to be displayed on no results

[image]

**OR**

**To Alter Exposed form options:**

- You need to implement `hook_form_alter()`
- Here is a sample code of it:

> ```
> function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
>     case 'views_exposed_form_id':
>     $name = 'Vocabulary_name';    
>     $myvoc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name); 
>   $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($myvoc->vid);     
>     foreach ($tree as $term) {        
>      $tax[$term->tid] = $term->name;  
>     }     
>     $form['field_taxonomy']['#options'] = $tax;  
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks for your support, first method works perfectly for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Better Expose Filter Module and within Views -> Exposed Form Style ->Choose (Better Exposed Filter) now in BEF settings -> Display "tid" exposed filter as -> Select (Default Select List) -> Show More options for "tid_1" -> see (Override "Any" option label ) -> write (-Select- )  then save the view . This will change the  to -Select- .