# Search API - how to have blank page on initial page load

Tags: views, search

I am using Search API with Apachesolr module. I have created a view on the index, but for some reason, before I do any search (or if I search for a blank screen) I get full results. How do I make the initial search screen blank? I tried setting the No Results setting in the view, but that only sets the text when you entered a bad search entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Views question than a Search API or Solr one, since the answer applies even when not using the latter. You want to set your "Exposed form style" to "Input required." See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139168/how-to-change-default-value-of-taxonomy-term-in-view-exposed-filter-drupal-7/139175#139175) for helpful screenshots.